# The problem is "ic_launcher" icon overwritten from aar 'cause the icon name is same

Tags: android

App icon starts to be exposed with another icon what I don’t want after I include aar.
And I found the reason why it's overwrtten 'cause both have a same name.
That's why if I change the name of app icon what I want, it works.

How can I choose a specific icon for the app through manifest?

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    ...
```

Comment: try changing names of the icon files

Comment: I see, all answer is I have to change the file name. I just wondered if I am able to choose specific one or not.

Comment: you can choose specific files in the project by navigating to the resource folder inside the  project directory.

Comment: I mean to choose either app/res/mipmap/ic_launcher or aar/res/mipmap/ic_launcher. I think I have to set the priority or write gradle script for that. How do you think of that?

Comment: how about deleting the ic_launcher inside aar package... do you need it for anything?

Comment: I really wanna do like that. But it's from 3rd party app that we got it from another company. But I can change the res name. I just wonder how to solve it in another way.

Answer (score 1):

have u tried changing the name of the icon that you want in the manifest, there will be no problem. also change it in the manifest file

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right, I can solve the problem if I changed the file name to not duplicated from others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your app icon name, you can do it without facing any problem and after changing the name of app icon you need to change also your icon name from your manifest too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you know to choose one specific file for app icon after the manifest files merged from app or aar?